# Mongo: How to update multiple records in one query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi i need a help for mongodb update multiple records in one query by array value:

**For This Data**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5edcd82197ace301c45ccb02"), 
    "date" : NumberInt(20200607),  
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5edcd82197ace301c45ccb03"), 
            "balance" : NumberInt(300),
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5edcd82197ace301c45ccb04"), 
            "balance" : NumberInt(200),
        }
    ]
}
```

**Query**

```
use auth;
db.getCollection("dailyreportbalace").updateMany(
    [{
        "_id": ObjectId("5edcd82197ace301c45ccb02"),
        "result._id": ObjectId("5edcd82197ace301c45ccb03")
    },{
        "_id": ObjectId("5edcd82197ace301c45ccb02"),
        "result._id": ObjectId("5edcd82197ace301c45ccb04")
    }],
    [{
        "$set": { "result.$.balance": NumberInt(60) }
    },{
        "$set": { "result.$.balance": NumberInt(80) }
    }],
    {upsert: true, multi: true}
)
```

**Error Query**
E QUERY    [js] Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators :

Comment: You are doing it wrong, if you look at the update [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/), the first parameter is `query`, and it can't be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider my comment.

> You are doing it wrong, if you look at the update [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/), the first parameter is `query`, and it can't be an array.

You need to use [`filtered positional operator`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html). Something like below:

```js
db.getCollection("dailyreportbalace").updateMany(
    {"_id": ObjectId("5edcd82197ace301c45ccb02")},
    {
        "$set": { 
            "result.$[elem1].balance": NumberInt(60),
            "result.$[elem2].balance": NumberInt(80) }
    },
    {
        upsert: true,
        multi: true,
        arrayFilters: [
            {"elem1._id": ObjectId("5edcd82197ace301c45ccb03")},
            {"elem2._id": ObjectId("5edcd82197ace301c45ccb04")}]
    }
)
```

Comment: Hey, was this helpful?